# Best resources for learning python in a 'class type setting'?

Tags: python

One of the best classes I took in college was Programming Languages where the prof would introduce a language or language concept, do a little playing with it in real time, and send us home with like 10 small little functions or programs to write that used what we learned in class and stretched it just enough to make sure you really understood what was going on.  I found that this style of learning was really enjoyable and engaging for me personally.

What I'm looking for is a resource, ideally one that's online, that is in the same vein.  Introduce basic operators -> make me use them.  Introduce functions -> make me use them.  Introduce recursion -> make me use it.  Ideally there are ~3 or so questions with answers not in plain view on the site so I won't cheat :)

While resources like [this](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) are good, they're not really what I'm looking for.  Thanks for any resources!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am teaching Python to graduate students at the University of Paris, and I exactly chose the kind of approach you like!  I could not agree more with how useful it can be.

I thus had to ask myself the same question as the one you ask here: I would recommend the following sources, in the given order:

1. [Instant Python](http://hetland.org/writing/instant-python.html): for a quick overview
2. [Learn Python in 10 minutes](http://www.poromenos.org/tutorials/python): another overview
3. [The official tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/): to be skimmed through, but with examples that you can try by yourself in the Python or IPython shell
4. [Building Skills in Python: A Programmer's Introduction to Python](http://homepage.mac.com/s_lott/books/python.html#book-python), by Stack Overflow contributor S. Lott (this book contains exercices)
5. [Dive into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/) is quite good too, but is limited to the now quite old Python 2.3. Update: the book now also exists [for Python 3](http://www.diveintopython3.net/).

You can certainly find other online books, and I did look at all of them a few months ago (while preparing my class!); but beware: some of them contain examples that are *not* examples of good practice.  The references above are a solid mix of theory and hands-on practice, and they cover a lot of material.

Answer (score 1):

Look at these:

- [Instant Hacking](http://hetland.org/writing/instant-hacking.html)
- [Learning to Program](http://www.freenetpages.co.uk/hp/alan.gauld/)
- [How to Think Like a Computer Scientist: Learning with Python](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python2e.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can play around with my [PythonTurtle](http://pythonturtle.org). Check out the help screen.

Answer (score 0):

[Dive](http://www.diveintopython.org/), do not walk, [into Python](http://www.diveintopython.org/).

Comment: That's a good reference, but as far as I can tell it doesn't have the leading questions that force me to use what I just read.

Answer (score 0):

As with any programming language, do the [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems) problems. But don't just hack together a solution - try and come up with a solution that is Pythonic - i.e. it uses the strengths of the language.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sage](http://www.sagenb.org/) for on-screen demonstrations. You can use pure python with it, but have the advantage of notebook interface. As a bonus, you can publish your sessions on the net, so the students can play with them.